# What is the purpose of a splitter?

Tags: device

I have a splitter SVI Digital SV-2G Splitter (5/1000MHz) from my Comcast high speed internet self-installation kit.

[image]

I try to understand what a splitter is used for, so I found this Wikipedia article
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_dividers_and_directional_couplers

> Power dividers (also power splitters and, when used in reverse, power
>   combiners) and directional couplers are passive devices used in the
>   field of radio technology. They **couple** a defined amount of the
>   electromagnetic power in a transmission line to a port enabling the
>   signal to be used in another circuit. An essential feature of
>   directional couplers is that they only couple power flowing in one
>   direction. Power entering the output port is not coupled to the input
>   port.

I am not sure what "couple" means, so I don't quite understand the quote in order to understand the purpose of a splitter.

My guess is there is one input (the top one) and two outputs (the lower two) for the splitter in the picture.

Are the two outputs two signals that are identical to the input? In other words, is a splitter used like a switch/router for Ethernet network?

Do the cables connected to both input and outputs belong to the same type, such as belonging to coaxial cable for the splitter in the picture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're interested in the practical reasons for this device, not just what it does electrically, so I'll answer for that perspective.

The *reason there is a splitter in the kit* is to allow you to connect both a TV and the provided cable modem — each requiring their own connection — to the cable coming into your house.

> My guess is there is one input (the top one) and two outputs (the lower two) for the splitter in the picture. Are the two outputs two signals that are identical to the input?

If you consider the top as an input, then the other two connectors are identical outputs. However, your cable modem transmits as well as receives, so there are signals traveling in both directions. The top should always be the one connected to the cable coming through your wall.

> In other words, is a splitter used like a switch/router for Ethernet network?

Not quite. It is not like an Ethernet switch, in that it is asymmetric: if you tried to communicate between the two bottom ports, you will see more signal loss than between either bottom port and the top port. With regard *how you connect it to devices*, the configurations are similar to a router (or switch with uplink port), but the actual electronic characteristics are completely different — for one thing, the splitter is a *[passive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_component#Classification)* device — it does not interpret or modify the signal, only pass it on, ideally unchanged (but somewhat reduced).

> Do the cables connected to both input and outputs belong to the same type, such as belonging to coaxial cable for the splitter in the picture?

This sounds like you are asking about some more general class of devices. I'm not sure what I could say about that class, but there's something interesting to be said about this splitter: yes, you do use all the same cables, and for good reason: an important characteristic of cables and connectors carrying high-frequency (RF) signals is *impedance*. Typical cable-TV hookups have an impedance of 75 ohms. If there is a mismatch at any point, then some of the signal passing through that point is *reflected*, and is effectively lost, for purposes of getting it to its intended destination.

If you've ever connected an indoor antenna to a TV, then perhaps you've seen a "300 ohm to 75 ohm" adapter with screw terminals, which besides adapting the connector also converts between impedances — it is a *matching transformer* (as well as a *balun*, which is another topic entirely).

A practical concern is that if you do *not* have a TV (or other cable device) as well as a cable modem connected to your cable service, you *should not* put the splitter in your line, because an unconnected port on a splitter is an impedance mismatch (specifically, it has infinite impedance, also known as an open circuit) which will degrade the signal for the other device. You could also connect a *terminator* to an unused port, which is just an appropriate resistor (75 ohm, for TV) across the conductors. However, it's better to leave out the splitter, because a splitter necessarily introduces a certain loss of signal (in order to split it evenly between the two ports).

(Impedance matching is also why coaxial cables should not be crushed or bent sharply; changing the shape changes the impedance.)

Comment: Thanks! (1) Is a splitter only used with certain type of cables? For example, with coaxial cables only? (2) Is a USB hub a kind of splitter for USB cables?

Comment: @Tim (1) A simple passive splitter is like a photocopier; both outputs are identical to the input (except at half the power). (2) Only superficially. A USB hub has circuitry to determine what to do with all the signals it receives. Mostly, this just involves routing input data to the appropriate output.

Answer (score 2):

They are commonly used to split cable lines and match impedance characteristics of a single line, while providing isolation from the split connection's potential to reflect backwards (towards the source). Much like a telephone splitter, you can split common RG-6 or RG-58/59 75ohm coax cable into one or more cable receivers (antennas in the old days).  One of our best sellers years ago at Radio Shack (and I suspect today as well).  I believe today's higher bandwidth cable receivers require the higher quality cable/connector(s) --RG6, whereas in the analog only days it didn't matter as much. Either crimp on connector will fit the splitter, but it is the cable characteristics that vary (RG-6 being wider for one).

some pros/cons:
http://www.ehow.com/way_5332417_rg-vs-rg-cables.html

- I wouldn't recommend the radio shack splitter as there are better quality ones (such as the brand you posted).

Answer (score 0):

The threaded connection are for F connectors used in television applications. This device splits the signal from a antenna to 2 TV sets or 2 antennas into 1 TV set. The only components inside this unit are 2 resistors. Nothing fancy.

It is also used for cable TV and cable modems for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

They should be ferrite core transformers, not resistors.

Resistors could be used, but they wouldn't isolate the two output (or used the other way, input) ports.  Little transformers do that.

Transformers will send half the signal (half power, or sqrt(1/2) voltage) out each port.

Resistors will send 1/4 out each port, and absorb half the signal.